# Link to send message is not displayed

Tags: 7, privatemsg, javascript

I am trying to get Privatemsg and DrupalGap working together.

I have installed both modules, configured the privileges and everything is working fine in the drupal site.

But with phonegap I am getting trouble displaying the 'Send this user a private message' link in the view of each user. I have set 'visible' the 'private msg' field in the drupalgap display in: admin/config/people/accounts/display/drupalgap but it's not working.

I have noticed It's always displaying only the history field even if I set to 'hidden' all the fields in the view configuration page: admin/config/people/accounts/display/drupalgap

I have cleared all caches.

What am I missing? How can I have the 'Send this user a private message' link displayed?

Answer (score 1):

DrupalGap's implementation of Private Message has not evolved enough to take into consideration any Private Message configuration set on a **DrupalGap** `Manage Display` page for User Entities.

That being said, I would recommend [creating your own page to custom render a User Entity](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Entities/Rendering_Entities). With these docs, essentially replace the usage of `node` with `user` and that'll give you a custom page in which you can render your users.

Then in your `page_callback` function to render the users, you can [add a widget](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Widgets) to the `content` render array, which could display a button that when clicked will navigate the user to a [custom DrupalGap form+page](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Forms/Creating_a_Custom_Form) where you can build the input elements (recipient, subject, message, etc).

Then in your form's submit handler, you'll actually [send the message to the user](https://github.com/signalpoint/privatemsg#send-a-new-private-message).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Putting privatemsg issue aside....in the user_view_pageshow(uid) function in the drupalgap core there is a line:
var view_mode = 'full';
It should be 
var view_mode = 'drupalgap';
right?